# apple requires credit card to download xcode

Tags: xcode

Does anyone have an "official" link to a direct download to xcode 4.1.

Apple no longer includes a install disk or a copy of xcode. They do offer a *free download from the new integrated app store but you have to have a apple account and a credit card.

Does anyone know a way around this.

Comment: ok I have downloaded xcode 3 but I have yet to find a way other than torrents to download xcode 4 without entering a credit card. PS sorry about being off topic.